What are some papers on cyclical poverty trap?
I am interested in the poverty trap models. Dynamically speaking, the model must exhibit multiple equilibria, as described in the below figure. (source)

I have seen many models that can formulate the dynamics of type a (on the left). Examples: Azariadis (1991), Ceroni (2001), Tabata (2003), Moav (2005), Chen (2010). For this type of dynamics, the 2 equilibria are locally stable.
My question is if there exists any model that can describe the dynamics of type b (on the right) where the lower steady state is a limit cycle, while the higher steady state is a sink. My intuition is that it must have something to do with expectation since myopia is the source of the limit cycle (as in Kaldo's cobweb model or de la Croix (1996)). Still, I am not aware of any literature that incorporates it into the poverty trap dynamics.
